# Issues getting bootstrap spacing right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble getting the spacing correct.
I need to have my carousel and cards the exact way as shown on the picture
[image]
However I can't get it, wether I'm using padding margin on bootstrap columns I just can't seem to get it.

col-9 seems to be fine for the carousel length wise but then I can't get the adequate spacing between the cards using offset (offset-1 makes the spacing way off)

Code

````
<div class="container" id="roomijs">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="card col-10">
            <div class="card-header card-head">
              Specialiteiten deze week
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div id="carousel-card-body" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#carousel-card-body" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel-card-body" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel-card-body" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner carousel-height">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/blanco.jpg" alt="First slide">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev carousel-control-left " href="#carousel-card-body" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next carousel-control-right" href="#carousel-card-body" role="button" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="card col-3">
            <div class="card-header">
              Featured
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
              <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card col-3">
            <div class="card-header">
              Featured
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
              <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card col-3">
            <div class="card-header">
              Featured
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
              <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>```
````

Comment: Could put together an example that can easily reproduce your issue?

Comment: Please accept the answer so others know the question is solved!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure you're following the [rules of the Bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#how-it-works)...

- columns and *only* columns should be the immediate children of `row`
- content goes inside columns

The code is breaking these rules. The row has been doubled up causing double negative margins around the carousel. Also, cards should be *inside* col and not the same div.

```
<div class="container" id="roomijs">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-9">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header card-head"> Specialiteiten deze week </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="carousel-card-body" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#carousel-card-body" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-card-body" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-card-body" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ol>
                        <div class="carousel-inner carousel-height">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="//via.placeholder.com/1500x600" alt="First slide">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="//via.placeholder.com/1500x600" alt="Second slide">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="//via.placeholder.com/1500x600" alt="Third slide">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="carousel-control-prev carousel-control-left " href="#carousel-card-body" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="carousel-control-next carousel-control-right" href="#carousel-card-body" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="card">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="card">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="card">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/ItCgA0euQV)